NextAuth: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accessToken')
i have an API login that receive 2 param: usernameOrEmail and password, after fetch success it will return 3 param: accessToken, refreshToken and tokenType. Then i have another API that receive accessToken and return user information, but when i tried to login the server return https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accessToken'). The API is successfully run in Postman
This is file 'api/auth/[...nextauth.js]':
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import axios from 'axios'
import { API_BASE_URL } from "@/config/apiConfig";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        usernameOrEmail: { label: 'Username or Email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const response = await axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}api/auth/login`, {
            usernameOrEmail: credentials.usernameOrEmail,
            password: credentials.password,
          }, {
            headers: {
              accept: '*/*',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          });
          const { accessToken, refreshToken, tokenType } = response.data;
          if (accessToken) {
            return {
              accessToken,
              refreshToken,
              tokenType,
            }
          }
          return null;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.response?.data?.message || 'Login failed');
        }
      },
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          redirect_uri: `oauth2/authorize/google?redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/oauth2/redirect`
        }
      }
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  session: {
    jwt: true
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token, user) {
      if (user) {
        token.accessToken = user.accessToken;
        token.refreshToken = user.refreshToken;
        token.tokenType = user.tokenType;
      }
      return token
    },
    async session(session, token) {
      if (token.accessToken) {
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
        session.refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
        session.tokenType = token.tokenType;
        try {
          const userResponse = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}api/auth/profile`, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token.accessToken}`,
            }
          });
          session.user = userResponse.data;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Failed to fetch user:", error.response?.data || error.message);
        }
      }
      return session
    }
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
})

This is file FormLogin.js:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Link from "next/link";
import { CustomTextField } from "./CustomTextField";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

const FormLogin = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    usernameOrEmail: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const [error, setError] = useState({
    usernameOrEmail: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const validateForm = () => {
    const newErrors = {};
    if (formData.usernameOrEmail.trim() === "") {
      newErrors.usernameOrEmail = "Email không được để trống";
    }

    if (formData.password.trim() === "") {
      newErrors.password = "Password không được để trống";
    }

    return newErrors;
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newErrors = validateForm();

    if (Object.keys(newErrors).length > 0) {
      setError(newErrors);
      return;
    }
    setError({});
    const result = await signIn('credentials', {
      redirect: false,
      usernameOrEmail: formData.usernameOrEmail,
      password: formData.password,
    })
    if (result.error) {
      setError({ form: result.error })
    } else {
      router.push('/product')
    }
  };

  const handleGoogleLogin = () => {
    signIn('google')
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-full py-[5rem]">
      <div className="w-2/5 p-4 m-auto bg-white rounded-2xl">
        <p className="mb-5 text-2xl font-bold text-center text-orange-gray text">
          Login
        </p>
        <form className="px-4">
          <CustomTextField
            className="mb-4"
            label="Tên đăng nhập hoặc Email"
            name="usernameOrEmail"
            value={formData.usernameOrEmail}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            fullWidth
            error={Boolean(error.usernameOrEmail)}
            helperText={error.usernameOrEmail}
          />
          <CustomTextField
            className="mb-4"
            label="Mật khẩu"
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={formData.password}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            fullWidth
            margin="normal"
            error={Boolean(error.password)}
            helperText={error.password}
          />
          <Link href={"#"}>
            <p className="text-base text-orange-gray hover:opacity-80">
              Quên mật khẩu?
            </p>
          </Link>
          <div className="flex justify-center gap-5 mt-4 ">
            <Button
              className="text-base font-semibold bg-light-brown text-orange-gray rounded-2xl hover:bg-light-brown hover:bg-opacity-80"
              type="submit"
              variant="contained"
              onClick={handleSubmit}
              size="large"
            >
              Đăng nhập
            </Button>

            <Button
              className="text-base font-semibold bg-light-brown text-orange-gray rounded-2xl hover:bg-light-brown hover:bg-opacity-80"
              type="submit"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="large"
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                router.push("/signup");
              }}
            >
              Đăng ký
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormLogin;

For example, the API should return like this:

{ "accessToken":
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzM4NCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0IiwiaWF0IjoxNzE2NzEzMjk5LCJleHAiOjE3MTY3MzQ3Mzl9.fxLO-c-w7RuCUigYzYLgeu1138icfDPZT0MuWgEby4XpJXq95fAfowl0hPjzV-DB",
"refreshToken":
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzM4NCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0IiwiaWF0IjoxNzE2NzEzMjk5LCJleHAiOjE3MTczMTgwOTl9.bEu-dYiD6eENiKQdIMPQKKl4PF7-c-u3hPrgiad_0ZJCxi5aPaYVVOt79okP9BMc",
"tokenType": "Bearer" }

